# Making a reverse pyramid with alternating symbols in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

As much as I hate to ask about homework questions, here is one I just can't seem to figure out. I'm supposed to make a reverse pyramid in the pattern of:

> AAAAAA
>
> BBBBB
>
> AAAA
>
> BBB
>
> AA
>
> B

I know I'm supposed to use a loop to manage this and I tried several different ones. I can do this thing perfectly fine with python with a loop and string multiplication, I have no idea how to do this in Java. Can anyone help?

Here is what I have so far, I need to figure out where to put in the line breaks and how to print out the second character instead of just the first one. Can anybody give an advice? Thanks in advance.

```
    static void drawLayeredPyramid(int numLayers, char firstChar, char secondChar){
    int i = numLayers;
    for (i = numLayers; i > 0; i--){
        if (i%2==0){
            for (int j = i; j > 0; j--){
                System.out.print(firstChar);
            }
        }
        if (i%2==1){
            for (int j = i; j > 0; j--){
                System.out.print(secondChar);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's how a for loop works in Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html. And here's the while loop: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html. If you know how to do it in Python, it means that you know the logic behind it. It's thus simply a syntax issue. Learn the syntax.

Comment: Advice for a programming student: play with it. Write what you think will work, then test it. If it doesn't work, try to figure out why. Repeat. That's how you learn.

Comment: What is the outer loop doing? Iterate, and print a layer at each iteration, right? A layer ends with an EOL, right? So, when should you print an EOL? You should be able to find this out by yourself. You can even adopt a brute-force approach and try printing it at various locations, and see how that goes. Again, experiment, learn from mistakes and repeat.

Comment: You had a few small errors in the code, and some things which were a bit out of normal conventions - you were very close though. I added an answer below, making the minimal changes to your code.  If it solves your issue, would you mind accepting the answer by clicking on the gray check mark next to it, making it green?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, in terms of printing the result you need. I made some minimal changes to your code:

```
static void drawLayeredPyramid (int numLayers, char firstChar, char secondChar) {
    for (int i = numLayers; i > 0; i--){
        if ((i%2)==0){
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                 System.out.print(firstChar);
            }
        }
        else {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                System.out.print(secondChar);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now since your outer `for` loop is iterating every time it needs to start a new layer, all you have to do is add `System.out.print("\n\n")` to the end of the loop.